# Is there a Rust ndarray equivalent for numpy arithmetic on a slice?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

The following Python code will repeatedly add the vector `[1, 2, 3, 4]` to  each row in the two-dimensional array `a`, starting only from the 20th row.

```py
import numpy as np

# an array of shape (100, 4)
a = np.zeros((100, 4), dtype=np.float32)

# and this is the operation explained above
a[20:, :] += [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0]
```

Is there a simple equivalent of this with `ndarray`?
I can already do what I need with more complicated messy looking code but feel there is probably a tidy ndarray.rs equivalent.

OK so, at the risk of over complicating a question I thought might have a simple answer that I just couldn't unearth...

I am using arrays of f32 shape (n, 8) representing three vertex locations, three normal components and two texture mapping coordinates. I am merging buffers from multiple 3D objects into one for more efficient graphics rendering. Within the 8 wide array the first three values need to be scaled i.e. multiplied by `&[sx, sy, sz]` then rotated using a standard `rz.dot(&rx.dot(&ry.dot()))` function and finally have a displacement `&[dx, dy, dz]` added. The normals just need to be rotated. My current system involves holding data in intermediate array variables.

```
use ndarray as nd;
array_buffer: nd::Array2<f32>, loc: &[f32; 3], scl: &[f32; 3]...
...
// scale then rotate new verts then add displacement
let new_verts = &new_buf.array_buffer.slice(s![.., 0..3]) * &nd::arr1(scl);
let new_verts = rotate_vec(rot, &new_verts) + &nd::arr1(loc);
// then add them to existing verts
let mut verts = nd::stack(nd::Axis(0),
                &[old_buf.array_buffer.slice(s![.., 0..3]),
                  new_verts.view()]).unwrap();
...
```

I know I won't be able to reduce it to the numpy one liner

```
verts = np.append(old_buf.array_buffer[:,0:3], 
        rotate_vec(rot, (new_buf.array_buffer[:,0:3] * scl) + loc))
```

but I thought that maybe some of the map or zip variants or macros might help me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That can be done with the same two steps as those performed in Python: [slicing](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.11.2/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#slicing), then *add-assigning* to a [broadcast](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.11.2/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#broadcasting) right-handed array.

```rust
use ndarray::Array2;

let mut a: Array2<f32> = Array2::zeros((100, 4));
{ 
    let mut slice = a.slice_mut(s![20.., ..]);
    slice += &ArrayView::from(&[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]);
}
```

Slicing is done with [`slice_mut`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.11.2/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.slice_mut) and the [`s!`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.11.2/ndarray/macro.s.html) macro for defining the intended range.
The outcome of a slice is a mutable array view, and so, most operations seen in [`ArrayBase`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.11.2/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html) are available, including arithmetic operations. 
By broadcasting rules, a right-handed array of shape `[4]` can be automatically broadcast to one of shape `[100, 4]` for the `+=` operator.

---

In case of other confusions in the transition from Python to Rust's `ndarray` crate, the documentation contains a [guide for Python users](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.11.2/ndarray/doc/ndarray_for_numpy_users/index.html).

Comment: thanks, I had initially tried putting things all into one line (the equivalent in your example of just doing a.slice_mut(s![20..,..]) += &array...; but it's probably much clearer to break it down

Comment: How can I assign rather than add-assign to the LHS?

Comment: @Ploppz `ArrayBase` has an [`assign`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.12.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.assign) method, which should do the trick.