# Perform broadcast additions between ndarray slices created from a numpy array

Tags: rust, multidimensional-array, pyo3, rust-ndarray

I'm trying to write a Rust code that could be called from Python. For simplicity, this code should just take a two-dimensional boolean array and XOR the second row to the first one. I've tried to write this code:

```rust
use numpy::PyArray2;
use pyo3::prelude::{pymodule, PyModule, PyResult, Python};

#[pymodule]
fn state_generator(_py: Python<'_>, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    #[pyfn(m)]
    fn random_cnots_transformation(_py: Python<'_>, x: &PyArray2<bool>) {
        let mut array = unsafe { x.as_array_mut() };
        let source = array.row(1);
        let mut target = array.row_mut(0);

        target ^= source;
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

but when compiling with `maturin` this fails with this error:

```rust
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<ViewRepr<&mut bool> as RawData>::Elem == ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
  --> src/lib.rs:35:16
   |
35 |         target ^= source;
   |                ^^ expected `bool`, found `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
   |
   = note: expected type `bool`
            found struct `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
   = note: required for `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&mut bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>` to implement `BitXorAssign<ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>: ScalarOperand` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:35:16
   |
35 |         target ^= source;
   |                ^^ the trait `ScalarOperand` is not implemented for `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `ScalarOperand`:
             bool
             isize
             i8
             i16
             i32
             i64
             i128
             usize
           and 9 others
   = note: required for `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&mut bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>` to implement `BitXorAssign<ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>>`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<ViewRepr<&bool> as RawData>::Elem == ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
  --> src/lib.rs:35:16
   |
35 |         target ^= source;
   |                ^^ expected `bool`, found `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
   |
   = note: expected type `bool`
            found struct `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
   = note: required for `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>` to implement `BitXorAssign`
   = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
   = note: required for `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&mut bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>` to implement `BitXorAssign<ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `ViewRepr<&bool>: DataMut` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:35:16
   |
35 |         target ^= source;
   |                ^^ the trait `DataMut` is not implemented for `ViewRepr<&bool>`
   |
   = help: the trait `DataMut` is implemented for `ViewRepr<&'a mut A>`
   = note: required for `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>` to implement `BitXorAssign`
   = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
   = note: required for `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&mut bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>` to implement `BitXorAssign<ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>>`
```

I thought that maybe this came from the fact that I used `^=`, so I tried tu use `+=` instead but this failed with this error:

```rust
error[E0368]: binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&mut bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
  --> src/lib.rs:35:9
   |
35 |         target += source;
   |         ------^^^^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         cannot use `+=` on type `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&mut bool>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
```

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50401760/11482728) but I'm not sure to see what's the difference here. If I'm not mistaken, the difference is that in my code, `array` is an `ArrayViewMut<bool, lx2>`, while in the answer it's an `Array2`.

What should I change in my code to perform such an operation?

If that matters, I'm using `cargo 1.72.0` and here's my `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "state_generator"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Tristan NEMOZ"]
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
ndarray = "0.15.6"
numpy = "0.19.0"
rand = "0.8.5"

[dependencies.pyo3]
version = "0.19.2"
features = ["extension-module"]
```

Comment: Why do people use unsafe code when they don't have to? Use [`.readwrite()`](https://docs.rs/numpy/latest/numpy/array/struct.PyArray.html#method.readwrite) instead.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman To be fair, I assumed there was no other way while following this tutorial: https://itnext.io/how-to-bind-python-numpy-with-rust-ndarray-2efa5717ed21

Adding a mutable variable `holder` to hold `x.readwrite()` and then setting `array` to `holder.as_array_mut()` works, thanks!

Comment: So we have the tutorial to blame ;P

Comment: Although I also partially blame `numpy` (the Rust library), if it followed the Rust conventions the names would be something like `as_array_mut()` and `as_array_mut_unchecked()` and this would be much easier to spot.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Definitely! 0:) I think I'll contact the author to tell them about this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is confusing, but the crux of it is that bitwise xor is implemented only with `&ArrayView` (more precisely, `&ArrayBase`), and not an owned `ArrayView`, so it's simple:

```rust
target ^= &source;
```

But then you'll face another error:

```rust
error: cannot borrow `array` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/lib.rs:5:22
  |
4 |     let source = array.row(1);
  |                  ------------ immutable borrow occurs here
5 |     let mut target = array.row_mut(0);
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
6 |
7 |     target ^= &source;
  |               ------- immutable borrow later used here
```

Which can be solved by using [an iterator over the rows](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.15.6/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.rows_mut):

```rust
let mut rows = array.rows_mut().into_iter();
let mut target = rows.next().unwrap();
let source = rows.next().unwrap();

target ^= &source;
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to do this modification and stumbled upon this error without knowing whether this was an improvement or not. As a side question, if I wanted to perform this operation between variables indexes, would converting to an iterator over the rows and iterate over it would still be the preferred way of doing such an operation?

Comment: @TristanNemoz Yeah, knowing whether a fix is the right thing to do when another error appears is sometimes challenging. Eventually you develop an intution for that, along with following the docs to see what is the correct form. In this case there's an addition hint, too: the first error is a type-checking error, but the "cannot borrow" error is a borrow checking error. Borrow checking is done only after type checking, and only if it succeeded. So if some fix make type errors to disappear but borrow error to appear instead, it is likely a correct fix, it means we at least type checking.

Comment: @TristanNemoz I don't understand what you mean by "variables indexes".

Comment: Suppose that instead of the `0` and `1` rows I pass the function two additional `u16` variables `target_index` and `source_index` and want to perform `array[target_index] += source_index`. I can definitely consume the iterator until reaching the indexes I'm looking for, but I wonder whether there is a more direct way to access these rows.

Comment: For now I use the `nth` method of the iterator which works well (as long as you remember that each call consumes the iterator), but I do have the feeling that it's suboptimal to consume a potentially large chunk of the iterator rather than accessing the direct memory I care about.

This is however a "Python reasoning", I'm not sure how time/memory consuming this approach actually is.

Comment: @TristanNemoz I think using `rows_mut()` is the best way. For slices, we have all the methods described in [How to get mutable references to two array elements at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30073684/7884305), but for ndarray rows, all we have is this iterator. You need to be careful with the calculation, though, remember to get the smaller index first and remember that `nth(n)` consumes `n + 1` elements from the iterator.

Comment: @TristanNemoz It appears (although I'm not sure), that the iterator can yield the nth element straight, which means it could overwrite `nth()` to be O(1). It doesn't in fact, but you can open an issue (or send a PR).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment. Do you mean that `nth` *should* act in O(1) time but actually doesn't, and this is what I should open an issue on? Or that the iterator should have another method to directly access an element from its index but actually doesn't?

Comment: @TristanNemoz The first thing. `nth()` can (and therefore should) be O(1), but is currently the default implementation and thus O(N).